# Set pagemargins and linedistance

Tags: margins, line-spacing

I'm using a template for this document and I want to set the margins to 2.5cm on each side. The top of my .tex file looks like this:

```
% $Id: $
\pdfpxdimen=1in

\divide\pdfpxdimen by 150

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
```

How can I set the margins to 2.5cm?

And another question: is it possible to have a different line-distance for the `abstract` part, and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [geometry package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/geometry) and the [setspace package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/setspace).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
\doublespacing
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{abstract}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```